# 2 connections to the same API in the same script. Do I need to ping both?

Tags: python, websocket

I'm connecting to an API that allows for subscriptions, so I read them every time there is a new message in the `.recv()` method and I pass them to the main function. This API will disconnect any connection automatically if my program is idle for a while. To solve this, they ping my program every 10 seconds (I can adjust that) and I need to respond to them sending a test_message to tell the server that I'm not idle.

I have a script with the form:

```
async def subscription_api(queue):
    #subscribe to various channels in the websocket and pass the response to the main function
    async with websockets.connect(api) as ws:
        await ws.send(json.dumps(subscription_msg))
        response = json.loads(await ws.recv())
        await queue.put(response)


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    subscription = asyncio.create_task(subscription_api(queue))
    #I need this api connection to send messages to the server in this function
    async with websockets.connect(api) as ws:
        subscription = await queue.get()
        if subscription == 'ping':
            #if the message I receive from the server is a ping, send a test_message
        else:
            #do stuff
```

Here I have 2 questions:

1. Even though I'm sending these test_messages back to the server, it still disconnects from time to time (once every 2-5 minutes aprox) raising an exception with the code 1006 (it doesn't specify the reason). Any idea why might that be, any common errors that might force this? I've been checking my code and haven't found a reason yet.
2. As you can see I have 2 connections in my code, one for each function (`async with websockets.connect(api) as ws:`). Are these 2 connections sharing every property, or do they count as 2 individual connections to the API and hence I should send the test messages for each one individualy so both of them 'tell' the server that they are not idle? Or is it enough to just send it in one connection because, again, they share the same properties?

Thanks!

Comment: 2 connections are 2 connections

Comment: Are you sure? Because then there should exist 1 instance of `connection.recv()` per connection. But in my case I only have one instance, in the connection1. So when I send a message via connection2, and the server responds with an answer, I'm able to pick up that answer via my receiver in connection1.

Comment: When I read your code more carefully, you have tow connections, but only one of them is actually doing anything. You have the one you connect in `subscription_api`, and the one you connect in `main`, and you completely ignore the one you connect in `main`. why?

Comment: You are kind of right. I divided the code in two connections to have it (way) more organized. The `subscription_api()` function reads the queued messages from the server, while the `main()` function works with those messages. It still requires a connection because `main()` sends some requests to the server, but all the responses from it are managed by `subscription_api()`

Comment: So then you have two connections to the server. 2 connections are 2 connections.

Comment: The problem is that when I send a message to the server from connection 2 ( in `main()`) and the server sends me back an answer, I can actually pick up that answer from my `connection.recv()` of the connection 1 (in subscription_api()`). How's that possible if they are truly 2 connections? Shouldn't the answers to my connection 2 requests get lost if they are completely separated? Thanks for your input!

Comment: Maybe the server sends it to all connections